How does rebuilding of widgets work in flutter is it based on keys or on the state or on runtime type of widget?
What happens when a new instance of a widget has same key as the old instance and the childrens have different state in the new widget instance?
In the Flutter docs, it says that The new Widget is considered to correspond to an existing Element if it has the same Type and Key.
Link to the doc
For example in the code below
Widget loadingStudent(List<int> absenteesList, int studentId) {
    return ListView.separated(
        key: someConstGlobalKey,
        addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Divider();
        },
        itemCount: studentsList.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return StudentCard(
            studentObject: studentsList[index],
            classAttendanceDetails: classAttendanceDetails,
            isLocked: widget.isLocked,
            course: course,
            studentId: studentsList[index].id,
            index: index,
            studentsList: studentsList,
            absenteeList: absenteesList,
            isAbsent: isAbsent(studentsList[index].id, absenteesList),
            currentlyMarkedStudentId: studentId,
            isLoading: true,
          );
        });
  }

  Widget loadedStudents(List<int> absenteesList) {
    return ListView.separated(
        key: someConstGlobalKey,
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Divider();
        },
        itemCount: studentsList.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return StudentCard(
            studentObject: studentsList[index],
            classAttendanceDetails: classAttendanceDetails,
            isLocked: widget.isLocked,
            course: course,
            studentId: studentsList[index].id,
            index: index,
            studentsList: studentsList,
            absenteeList: absenteesList,
            isAbsent: isAbsent(studentsList[index].id, absenteesList),
            currentlyMarkedStudentId: -1,
            isLoading: false,
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var bloc = BlocProvider.of<MarkAttendanceBloc>(context);
    bloc.add(InitialEvent(
        absenteeList: classAttendanceDetails.absentees,
        studentsList: studentsList,
        course: course));
    return BlocBuilder<MarkAttendanceBloc, MarkAttendanceState>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, MarkAttendanceState state) {
      var nextView;

      state.when(
        loadingStudent: (int? presentCount, int absentCount,
            List<int> absenteesList, int studentId) {
          nextView = loadingStudent(absenteesList, studentId);
        },
        loaded: (int presentCount, int absentCount, bool localOperation,
            List<int> absenteesList) {
          nextView = loadedStudents(absenteesList);
        },
        error: (int? presentCount, int? absentCount, String errorMessage) {
          nextView = Text(errorMessage);
        },
        loading: (
          int? presentCount,
          int? absentCount,
        ) {
          nextView = CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      );
      return nextView;
    });
  }

I expect nothing to happen when the nextView changes from loadedStudents to loadingStudent and then again the loadedStudents widget as the ListView.separated is returned from both the widgets, hence having the same type, and they have the same key attached, but I see the child widget states are updated. When the absenteeList is modified.
So this made me curious about how rebuilding actually happens when widgets are provided a key and also when they are not provided any key.

Each student card has a button to mark them absent or present; once you press it, the absentee list is updated, and the loading widget is shown until the response is received from the API for that student card. Now, if I use the same key  for the loadingStudent and loadedStudent listView, I expect that the loadedStudents listview will be rendered instead of the new instance of loadingStudent. I am trying to understand that if the key is the same for both the listView Widgets, then no change should be shown, and the previous listView should be rendered with the same state.

I am trying to understand the working of the keys here and nothing else. This is not what my code is intended to do, but I am just trying to understand the rebuilding process with keys and without them
